# Is there a difference between "lo" and "behold"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I noticed, while going through the King James Bible, that the translators will translate a particular greek word as both "lo" and "behold." It seems like it is interchangeable to them. However, I don't know if there is more meaning to the difference, and if anybody could share insight into why they would do so?

The common phrase, "lo and behold" seems to indicate they are not of the same meaning.

Here are two examples:

"**Behold**, I send you forth as sheep in the midst of wolves: be ye therefore wise as serpents, and harmless as doves." (Matthew 10:16)

"Then Peter said, **Lo**, we have left all, and followed thee." (Luke 18:28)

If there is no difference, why did the phrase "lo and behold" come about? There is another question about that phrase, but it doesn't really address this, I think.

If there is a difference, it would be interesting to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Report what you found in a dictionary.

Comment: So you would say *cease* can't be a synonym for *desist* because we use the phrase *cease and desist*? How about *intents and purposes*? *Hopes and dreams?* *Traps and pitfalls?* *Thoughts and ideas?*

Comment: The deliberate repetition of ideas, expressed differently with each repetition, was desirable and was even indicative of an author’s eloquence and learning in old examples of formal prose, like the Bible. (It may be relevant to note that in Renaisance rhetoric Erasmus taught *copia* or “twofold abundance” in expression.) To modern ears, out of context, the result is “flowery language”. “Plain English” is valued, where the most appropriate word is employed and where redoubling an idea or concept is less likely, but by no means impossible.

Comment: Legal language, where very old and “learned” expressions are preserved in technical jargon, is a good source of other examples - where synonyms (or words close in meaning) repeat the original idea. Peter Shor has mentioned “cease and desist” but “aid and abet” and “will and testament” are others.

Comment: @PeterShor and Orbital Aussie that redundancy though comes from a particular history and context of language change when Old French words began predominating over Old English words. These [doublets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_doublet) were used to ensure understanding in the midst of language change. This is not to say redundancy is not a poetic device, but the legal examples do not here apply

Comment: Actually, I believe that _lo_ means look, and _behold_ means to absorb then what you see. So the pair has the doubling power others note without really repeating meaning. I see a chronology in the imperatives.

Comment: If you want to know why a particular word was translated a particular way, our sister site on [Hermeneutics.SE] will likely give more useful answers.

Comment: I have considered the comments and studied more. It appears to me like "lo" and "behold" are not used interchangeably, really. 

"Lo" is used to draw one's attention to a remarkable or unusual event taking place at the moment. It is normally directed to hearers. "Behold" seems to have a more general usage in describing all kinds of events, in narrative.

I guess that is neither here nor there, but there is not much material about the use of the word "lo," online, so I just studied it's 159 uses in the KJ and some other sources. 

The uses lend themselves to Yosef's comment pretty well.